# Pass an array through an AJAX POST using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My POST function doesn't pass the `data[]` array at all. Is my array correct? Or is my POST function missing something?

```js
function doAction(prefix) {
  if ($('#' + prefix + '_actions').val() == 'update') {
    var data = [];
    
    for (i = 1; i != 500; i++) {
      if (document.getElementById(prefix + '_region' + i).value == "") {
        $.post('../../wp-content/themes/wine_district/partials/macave.php', {
            client: document.getElementById('currentClient').value,
            'data[]': data,
            action: 'i_update'
          },
          function(result) {
            showData(document.getElementById('currentClient').value);
          });
        break;
      } else {
        data['region' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_region' + i).value;
        data['appellation' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_appellation' + i).value;
        data['domaine' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_domaine' + i).value;
        data['cepage' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_cepage' + i).value;
        data['millesime' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_millesime' + i).value;
        data['format' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_format' + i).value;
        data['nombre' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_nombre' + i).value;
        data['casier' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_casier' + i).value;
        data['caisse' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_caisse' + i).value;
        data['remarque' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_remarque' + i).value;
        data['notes' + i] = document.getElementById(prefix + '_notes' + i).value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You're adding random properties to the array. That's not going to be serialised when sending the data over. Either use an object or use an array properly - with only numeric indexes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can solve issue by stringify the array and then pass to post call

e.g.
data: JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: An array with random properties added to it will be serialised into an empty array.